# Can I use a domain account in OPENDATASOURCE()

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying and failing to use a domain account in SQL Server's OPENDATASOURCE().

I've tried many variations, including the following:

```
OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=<server name>; User ID=<domain>\<user>; Password=<password>' )
```

I've also tried escaping the backslash like this:

```
OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=<server name>; User ID=<domain>\\<user>; Password=<password>' )
```

I get following error message in the first case:

```
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user '<domain>\<user>'
```

In the second case, I get the same except that I see both backslashes in the error message.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?
Also, the password includes a backtick (`) character. Is that forbidden in OPENDATASOURCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No OleDb drivers support using Windows Auth with provided username/password.  The only way to use Windows Auth is by impersonating the user, injecting the user's credentials in the Windows Credential Store, or using `runas /netonly`.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: To use a backtick or special char in the password you need to encapsulate in double quotes

For example, if your password is "`password", you may need to enter like:

```sql
OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=server_name;uid=domain\username;pwd="`password"')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That doesn't work--gives the same result.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update. I tried surrounding the password with double quotes and got the same result. I then tried the same login in a different situation to make sure I hadn't gotten it locked with too many bad-password attempts. The login still works--I just haven't been able to use it in OPENDATASOURCE.